# There's a way to include more than one field in combobox control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a combobox (DropDownList) control in my aspx project, linked to a datasource. I would like to show more than one field on the dataTextField (like in MS-Access). It's possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify more than one DataTextField.  You need to figure out how to get the fields combined before databinding.

Generally, I accomplish this by modifying the query from the database.  For example, if I wanted a full name of an employee in a drop-down list, I'd use the query

```
Select EmployeeNumber, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName from EmployeeTable
```

And set the DataTextField to FullName

If you don't have the flexibility to modify the query (for example, if you don't have rights to the database and are using a stored procedure set up by a DBA), you'd need to instead populate the drop-down in the code-behind.  Perhaps have the query fill a DataTable, add a column to the DataTable, and set the newly added Column's value to be the FirstName + ' ' + LastName and set the DataTextField accordingly.

However, the first solution is better in my opinion because it's easier to change teh query (or stored procedure) than to change the code, recompile, and deploy if it needs to change down the road.

Comment: Good. It works! I suggest using CAST in SQL for correctly parsing the query.